# What is the equivalent of DATEVALUE in Google sheets to Postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, google-sheets

I am trying to replicate a report from Google sheets to Postgres. In Google sheets one of the column is calculated using the formulae `DATEVALUE` which converts date to a numeric value.

In Google sheets `DATEVALUE('2023-18-05')` is equal to `45064`

Need to achieve similar output in Postgres.

What is the equivalent function for the same in Postgres?
If there is no equivalent function how to approach to solve the same in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This `'2023-18-05'` does not look like a valid format and when I try it in Google Sheets it fails. Should it not be `'2023-05-18'`?.
2. The output in this case `45064` is Google Sheets specific as detailed here [Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) and is the days from `1899-12-30`

Given 2) then:

```
select '2023-05-18'::date - '1899-12-30'::date;
45064
```

Which you could encapsulate in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.google_days(in_dt date)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
select in_dt - '1899-12-30'::date;
$function$

select google_days('2023-5-18');
 google_days 
-------------
       45064
```